# Knight's Tour - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess

Below is my recursive solution for the [Knights Tour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour). The user can set the board size and the program will print the **first** legal knight's tour it finds.

As there are potentially millions of correct solutions to the knight's tour, only one solution is given.

```
def legal_moves(visited, position, sq):
    """Calculate legal moves"""
    legal_moves = [
        (-2, -1),
        (-2, 1),
        (-1, -2),
        (-1, 2),
        (1, -2),
        (1, 2),
        (2, -1),
        (2, 1),
    ]

    row = position // sq
    col = position % sq

    move_to = []
    for dx, dy in legal_moves:
        if 0 <= (row + dx) < sq and 0 <= (col + dy) < sq:
            new_position = (position + (sq * dx)) + dy
            if new_position not in visited and 0 <= new_position < (sq * sq):
                move_to.append(new_position)
    return move_to


def make_move(move_to, visited, current, route, sq):
    """Carry out the move"""
    for move in move_to:
        visited.add(current)
        new_route = route + f"{current}-"
        solution_found = next_move(visited, move, new_route, sq)
        visited.remove(current)
        if solution_found:
            return True
    return False


def next_move(visited, current, route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and instruct "make_move" to carry them out"""
    if len(visited) == (sq * sq) - 1:
        route += f"{current}"
        print(route)
        return True
    move_to = legal_moves(visited, current, sq)
    solution_found = make_move(move_to, visited, current, route, sq)
    if solution_found:
        return True


def start_tour(sq):
    """Calculate the knights tour for  grid sq*sq starting at all positions in range 0-sq"""
    for starting in range(sq * sq):
        visited = set()
        route = ""
        solution_found = next_move(visited, starting, route, sq)
        if solution_found:
            return
    print("No knights tour could be calculated")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    square_size = 8
    start_tour(square_size)
```

**EDIT**
I have added a `print_route` function which is called from inside `next_move` in place of the current `print` statement as follows:
`print_route(route, sq)`

```
def print_route(route, size):
    """Convert the 1D array into a 2D array tracking the movement on the knight"""
    import numpy as np

    steps = route.split("-")
    array = np.zeros(size * size)

    for index, item in enumerate(steps):
        array[int(item)] = index + 1
    array = array.reshape(size, size)

    print(array)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Starting position**

If there is a route to be found, it will go through cell 0 and will be found at first iteration of `start_tour`. We can remove the loop and just have `starting = 0`.

**Generating legal moves**

Various details can be improved in the `legal_moves` function.

This is a good occasion to use a generator with the keyword `yield`.

We could compute `row` and `col` with a single call to `divmod`.

We could make computation of new position more straight-forward with intermediates variables for coordinates on each axis.

Because of the way `new_position` is computed, there is no need for the additional boundary check.

We'd get something like:

```
def generate_new_positions(visited, position, sq):
    """Yield legal moves"""
    generate_new_positions = [
        (-2, -1),
        (-2, 1),
        (-1, -2),
        (-1, 2),
        (1, -2),
        (1, 2),
        (2, -1),
        (2, 1),
    ]
    # position = row * sq + col
    row, col = divmod(position, sq)

    for dx, dy in generate_new_positions:
        x, y = row + dx, col + dy
        if 0 <= x < sq and 0 <= y < sq:
            new_pos = x * sq + y
            if new_pos not in visited:
                yield new_pos
```

**Separation of concerns: printing vs returning a result**

When a result is found, it is printed and a boolean (or None) is returned in the different functions. It would be easier to return either None or the result found and to have that result printed from a single point of the logic.

We'd have something like:

```
def make_move(move_to, visited, current, route, sq):
    """Carry out the move"""
    for move in move_to:
        visited.add(current)
        new_route = route + str(current) + "-"
        solution_found = next_move(visited, move, new_route, sq)
        visited.remove(current)
        if solution_found:
            return solution_found
    return None


def next_move(visited, current, route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and instruct "make_move" to carry them out"""
    if len(visited) == (sq * sq) - 1:
        route += str(current)
        return route
    move_to = generate_new_positions(visited, current, sq)
    return make_move(move_to, visited, current, route, sq)


def start_tour(sq):
    """Calculate the knights tour for grid sq*sq starting at all positions in range 0-sq"""
    starting = 0
    visited = set()
    route = ""
    return next_move(visited, starting, route, sq)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for square_size in 3, 5, 6:
        ret = start_tour(square_size)
        print("No knights tour could be calculated" if ret is None else ret)
```

Also, formatting the string could be done in a single place as well. We could use lists for instance in all the logic.

```
def make_move(move_to, visited, current, route, sq):
    """Carry out the move"""
    for move in move_to:
        visited.add(current)
        new_route = route + [current]
        solution = next_move(visited, move, new_route, sq)
        visited.remove(current)
        if solution:
            return solution
    return None


def next_move(visited, current, route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and instruct "make_move" to carry them out"""
    if len(visited) == (sq * sq) - 1:
        return route + [current]
    move_to = generate_new_positions(visited, current, sq)
    return make_move(move_to, visited, current, route, sq)

def start_tour(sq):
    """Calculate the knights tour for grid sq*sq starting at all positions in range 0-sq"""
    starting = 0
    visited = set()
    route = []
    return next_move(visited, starting, route, sq)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for square_size in 3, 5, 6:
        ret = start_tour(square_size)
        print("No knights tour could be calculated" if ret is None else "-".join((str(e) for e in ret)))
```

**Reducing the duplicated information**

We're maintaining a `visited` set and a `route` list: both containing roughtly the same data. Maybe we could recompute `visited` from the `route` when we need it.

```
def make_move(move_to, current, route, sq):
    """Carry out the move"""
    for move in move_to:
        solution = next_move(move, route + [current], sq)
        if solution:
            return solution
    return None

def next_move(current, route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and instruct "make_move" to carry them out"""
    if len(route) == (sq * sq) - 1:
        return route + [current]
    move_to = generate_new_positions(set(route), current, sq)
    return make_move(move_to, current, route, sq)

def start_tour(sq):
    """Calculate the knights tour for grid sq*sq starting at all positions in range 0-sq"""
    return next_move(0, [], sq)
```

**Simplifying the logic**

Having a function A calling a function B itself calling B can make things hard to understand properly because both A and B are hard to understand independently.

Here, we could get rid of `make_move` by integrating directly in `next_move`:

```
def next_move(current, route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and carry them out"""
    if len(route) == (sq * sq) - 1:
        return route + [current]
    for move in generate_new_positions(set(route), current, sq):
        solution = next_move(move, route + [current], sq)
        if solution:
            return solution
    return None
```

**More simplification**

In `next_move`, `route` is almost always used in the expression `route + [current]`. We could directly define this at the beginning of the function:

```
def next_move(current, route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and carry them out"""
    new_route = route + [current]
    if len(new_route) == (sq * sq):
        return new_route
    for move in generate_new_positions(set(new_route), current, sq):
        solution = next_move(move, new_route, sq)
        if solution:
            return solution
    return None
```

More importantly, it leads to the question: why do we provide a route AND an element to add to it instead of just having that element in the list.

```
def next_move(current, route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and carry them out"""
    if len(route) == (sq * sq):
        return route
    for move in generate_new_positions(set(route), current, sq):
        solution = next_move(move, route + [move], sq)
        if solution:
            return solution
    return None

def start_tour(sq):
    """Calculate the knights tour for grid sq*sq starting at all positions in range 0-sq"""
    start = 0
    return next_move(start, [start], sq)
```

Going further, we do not really the `current` argument anymore as we can compute it from `route`.

```
def next_move(route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and carry them out"""
    if len(route) == (sq * sq):
        return route
    current = route[-1]
    new_pos = generate_new_positions(set(route), current, sq)
    for move in new_pos:
        solution = next_move(route + [move], sq)
        if solution:
            return solution
    return None

def start_tour(sq):
    """Calculate the knights tour for grid sq*sq starting at all positions in range 0-sq"""
    start = 0
    return next_move([start], sq)
```

**Final code**

```
def generate_new_positions(visited, position, sq):
    """Yield legal moves"""
    generate_new_positions = [
        (-2, -1),
        (-2, 1),
        (-1, -2),
        (-1, 2),
        (1, -2),
        (1, 2),
        (2, -1),
        (2, 1),
    ]
    # position = row * sq + col
    row, col = divmod(position, sq)

    for dx, dy in generate_new_positions:
        x, y = row + dx, col + dy
        if 0 <= x < sq and 0 <= y < sq:
            new_pos = x * sq + y
            if new_pos not in visited:
                yield new_pos


def next_move(route, sq):
    """Find the next valid moves and carry them out"""
    if len(route) == (sq * sq):
        return route
    current = route[-1]
    new_pos = generate_new_positions(set(route), current, sq)
    for move in new_pos:
        solution = next_move(route + [move], sq)
        if solution:
            return solution
    return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for square_size in 3, 5, 6:
        ret = next_move([0], square_size)
        print("No knights tour could be calculated" if ret is None else "-".join((str(e) for e in ret)))
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. It does make a lot of sense to use visited and route for the same purpose. I'm not sure why I didn't do this in the first place. I really like the way you return the function. It makes a lot more sense to me than returning the result of a function. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Precomputed Moves

You are computing a lot of integer quotients and remainders.  (@Josay's solution as well).  You can reduce the amount of work done during the solving of the Knight's Tour by pre-computing the positions which can be reached from each square:

```
legal_moves = (-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1)
moves = [ [ (r+dr) * cols + (c+dc) for dr, dc in legal_moves
            if 0 <= r+dr < rows  and  0 <= c+dc < cols ]
          for r in range(rows) for c in range(cols) ]
```

I've used `rows` and `cols` here, to generalize from a square board to an NxM board.  After this point, the logic doesn't change.

Now `moves[0]` is a list of all (both) positions that can be reached from square #0, `moves[1]` is a list of the 3 positions that can be reached from square #1, and so on.  Note that you never need to deal with the dimension of the board again.  No integer division or modulo remainders; just use the square's index number.

### Visited

Your `visited` set is a nice way, to keep track of whether or not a position has been visited or not.  In \$O(1)\$ time, you can tell if you've reached a visited location or not.  @Josay's suggestion of using `set(route)` to recompute the set of visited locations removes the need for maintaining a separate global `set()` structure, but the cost is recreating the `set(route)` each move.  This is at least \$O(N)\$ per move, a huge decrease in performance.

A different structure for keeping track of `visited` locations is to simply use an array of positions.  If `visited[move]` is `True`, you've been there, if not, you haven't.  This is faster that using a `set()`; you a just looking up an index.  It is \$O(1)\$ with a very small constant.

Better: `visited[move] = move_number`.  Initialize the array to `0` to start with every spot unvisited, and mark a `1` in the first move location, `2` in the second and so on.  Set `visited[move] = 0` when you back-track.  No need to keep track of the `route`, as it is implicit in the `visited[]` array.  `print_route()` amounts to reshaping the `visited` array into a 2D array, and printing it.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I am always dubious about using multi-line ```for``` loops and especially nested ```list comprehension``` because I have always read that if the  code can be written in roughly the same number of lines with a similar space complexity (in my case it is O(1)) then it is better to use the more readable solution. Having said that I do think its a nice solution!